# Preserve line breaks with htmlentities?

Tags: php

In a form that I'm building, I have `textareas` which will include a nice amount of text, with line breaks included, such as:

> Sentence one
>
> Sentence two

I am posting this to my form by using `htmlentities`, ex:

```
. htmlentities($_POST['textarea']) .
```

This however, produces the following in the email (**HTML email**) that gets sent by the form:

> Sentence one Sentence two

Is there anyway to preserve line breaks with `htmlentities`?

Comment: Is the mail plain-text or html? If it’s html, `\n` won’t do anything, you will have to call `nl2br()` to transform line breaks into <br>.

Comment: HTML, I'll add that bit of info to the post.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) which converts `\n` to `<br />`:

```
. nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['textarea'])) .
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible. If you want a line break in an HTML document then you have to use either a `display: block` (and friends) element, a line break element (`<br>`) or a `white-space: pre` element.

You can generate `<br>` elements using PHP with the [`nl2br`](http://php.net/nl2br) function.